# Turning for Loop into forEach. Passing any array of numbers as argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I am Working on a function that returns de minimum (or max.) value in an array of numbers.
Looks like this one forLoop below works right :

```
const myNumbersAr = [-1300, 120, 12, -2000, -58]
const mySecondAr = [-100, 200, -300, 400, 500]

var findMinNumber = function (oneArray) {
    var minNumber = oneArray[0]
    for (i = 0; i < oneArray.length; i++) {       
        if (oneArray[i] < minNumber) {
        minNumber = oneArray[i]     
        } 
    } 
    console.log(minNumber)
}

findMinNumber(myNumbersAr) // returns -2000
findMinNumber(mySecondAr) // returns -300
```

But since I am practising, I would like to turn it into a forEach. But I dont get it right. This is what I try :

```
var findMinNumber = function (someArray) {
    var minNumber = someArray[0];
    someArray.forEach(function (someArray) {
        
        if (someArray[i] < minNumber) {
            
            minNumber = someArray[i]
        
        }
        
    })
   console.log(minNumber)
}

findMinNumber(myNumbersAr) // returns always myNumbersAr[0] position.
```

I get that passing the argument twice (someArray) , doesnt sounds right, so I guess I should maybe order it differently?

Comment: You need `function (element)` and then just `element` instead of  `someArray[i]`. But may I ask why `forEach` and not `for of`? `for (let element of someArrary)` has the benefit that `return` still does what you expect, you can still use `break` and `continue`, etc

Comment: Look at [examples of and documentation for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) `forEach`. Notice what the arguments passed to the callback are.

Comment: @CherryDT no special reason other than that is what I've learnt so far. I am going step by step, trying to practise with every new element i learn. I am just following a small program and so fat, it only showed us forloops / while and forEach as a way to iterate over arrays. 
I guess a bit further down the road, when I have more of a grasp about these, I will move to ´´´for of ´´´

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I will, thanks! although I still lack of a lot knowledge to understand some parts of the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```js
var findMinNumber = function (someArray) {
var minNumber = someArray[0];
someArray.forEach(function (someItem) {
    if (someItem < minNumber) {
        minNumber = someItem
    }
})
return minNumber;
}
const myNumbersAr = [-100, 200, -300, 400, 500]
console.log(findMinNumber(myNumbersAr));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think i see why, but anyway, may I ask why if I point to one of the positions `someItem[i]`, i just get the position stored in `var minNumber`?
I thought that since it iterates over the array, that `[i]`might change, the same way as it does with the forLoop

Comment: In this case `someItem` = -100 on the first iteration, 200 on the 2nd iteration, etc.  `someItem[i]` (assuming `i` is an integer like 0 or 1) is undefined, as you're treating `someItem` as if it were an array, which it's not.

Comment: Also in your previous loop, you define `i` here: `for (i = 0;`.  In your second loop, `i` is undefined.